# JDBC connection returns true with no parameters

Tags: java, jdbc

I am building gui where is a button that tests if database has connection. User has to give database parameters and then it must click "Test connection" button to see if database connects. But my problem is that, even if I give no parameters, it still returns true for connection.

Here is my code:

**GUI part where inputs are sent as database parameters:**

```
testConnection.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        DatabaseController dbController = new DatabaseController(databaseUrl.getText(), databaseName.getText(),
                databaseUser.getText(), databasePassword.getText());
        if(dbController.isDataBaseConnected()) setDatabaseConnectionStatus(connectionSuccessLabel, Color.green);
        else setDatabaseConnectionStatus(connectionFailLabel, Color.red);
    });
```

**Database controller class**

```
package dbConnection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseController{

private Connection connection;

public DatabaseController(String url, String dbName, String user, String password){
    defineDatabaseParameters(url, dbName, user, password);
    this.connection = new DbConnection()
            .connectToDatabase();
}

public boolean isDataBaseConnected(){
    System.out.println(connection);
    if(connection == null){
        return false;
    } else {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

private void defineDatabaseParameters(String url, String dbName, String user, String password){
    DbConnection.DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://" + url + "/" + dbName.trim();
    DbConnection.USER = user.trim();
    DbConnection.PASS = password.trim();
}

}
```

**And here is my database parameters class**

```
package dbConnection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DbConnection {

//   static String      JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
//   static String      DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/*********";
//  
//   static String      USER = "root";
//   static String      PASS = "";

 static String      JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
 static String      DB_URL;

 static String      USER ;
 static String      PASS ;

 public Connection connectToDatabase(){
     Connection conn = null;
     try {
         System.out.println("Outpost 1: " + DB_URL);
         System.out.println("Outpost 2: " + USER);
         System.out.println("Outpost 3: " + PASS);
         Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
     } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return conn;
 }
 }
```

Now when I press "Test connection" button and give no parameters (empty strings), then it still shows connection successful. What am I doing wrong that it still returns true? Here is logging output:
**console output**

`Outpost 1: jdbc:mysql:///
Outpost 2: 
Outpost 3: 
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@e29ae34`

Comment: I tried your code and got "Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Comment: I think probably your code is different from you posted.

Comment: I tried with this code:  String databaseUrl = "";
  String databaseName = "";
  String databaseUser = "";
  String databasePassword = "";
  
  DatabaseController dbController = new DatabaseController(databaseUrl, databaseName,
                databaseUser, databasePassword);
        if(dbController.isDataBaseConnected()) 
         System.out.println("OK");
        else 
         System.out.println("WRONG");

Comment: @reos is your conclusion now that access is denied but indeed there is a connection? Perhaps we are dealing with a database which accepts blank user / password and a blank url leading to localhost?

Comment: I think that if the connection exist (not null) then it could be created before. And you're accessing the method connectToDatabase from other class different from you post. Or a different action listener. Probably the action listener doesn't create  DatabaseController  and uses one created before. I recommend you to try first using a main method, and inside it put the code of my previous comment.

Comment: *Your code* returns true. JDBC is returning a connection. Your title is confused.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys. I solved my problem like this. I made all my input fields required, which means user has to add some URL (for some reason mySQL likes empty url too and gives connection) and added return false to my isDataBaseConnected() method in DatabaseController class. See edits above